# Filter a view with contextual authored date

Tags: views, 8, nodes, datetime

I have a Drupal 8 view where I want to sort nodes by authored year using  contextual filters.

So www.mysite.com/2017

will list all nodes from 2017.

I set up the filter using 'Content: Created Year' which takes YYYY format.

But the filter is ignored.

www.mysite.com/2017 returns all years.

What did I miss?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the placeholder `%` to the path (in the main views UI in the middle column under "Page settings"),

e.g. something like `my-view/by-year/%` which will accept URLs like `my-view/by-year/2019`

Comment: Thanks. Forgot about that step. That did it.

Comment: @edg You should accept Hudri's answer as the correct one if it solved the problem.

Comment: I spoke too soon. The % is not essential for the original problem. I scrapped the view and started afresh and it worked both with and without the %. The % is useful if you need your dynamic value in the path e.g. www.mysite.com/%/feed . Not sure what fixed it.

Comment: My problem was probably related to caching. By default, the view's tag based caching is on (under 'Advanced') so any changes I made were probably not updating. The good news is the contextual filter now works for me as advertised. Thanks Hudri for your response